# Replace part of the string from reference string

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a String ArrayList consisting alphabets followed by a digit as a suffix to each of the alphabet.

```
ArrayList <String> baseOctave = new ArrayList();
baseOctave.add("S1");
baseOctave.add("R2");
baseOctave.add("G4");
baseOctave.add("M2");
baseOctave.add("P3");
baseOctave.add("D1");
baseOctave.add("N1");
```

I pass the strings from this baseOctave and few other characters as input pattern for creating an object.
    MyClass obj1 = new MyClass ("S1,,R2.,M2''-");
Since I frequently make use of these kind of input patterns during object instantiation, I would like to use simple characters S, R, G, M etc.
Ex:

```
   MyClass obj1 = new MyClass ("S,,R.,M''-");
    MyClass obj2 = new MyClass ("S1,G.,M,D1");
```

So the alphabets used during object creation may contain digits as suffix or it may not have digit as suffix.

But inside the constructor (or in separate method), I would like to replace these simple alphabets with alphabets having suffix. The suffix is taken from the baseOctave.
Ex: above two strings in obj1 and obj2 should be "S1,,R2.,M2''-" and "S1,G4.,M2,D1"

I tied to do this, but could not continue the code below. Need some help for replacing please..

```
 static void addSwaraSuffix(ArrayList<String> pattern) {

        for (int index = 0; index < pattern.size(); index++) {
            // Get the patterns one by one from the arrayList and verify and manipulate if necessary.
            String str = pattern.get(index);

            // First see if the second character in Array List element is digit or not.
            // If digit, nothing should be done. 
            //If not, replace/insert the corresponding index from master list
            if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(1)) != true) {

                // Replace from baseOctave.

                str = str.replace(str.charAt(0), ?);    // replace with appropriate alphabet having suffix from baseOctave.

                // Finally put the str back to arrayList.
                pattern.set(index, str);
            }
        }
    }
```

Edited information is below:
Thanks for the answer. I found another solution and works fine. below is the complete code that I found working. Let me know if there is any issue.

```
static void addSwaraSuffix(ArrayList<String> inputPattern, ArrayList<String> baseOctave) {
        String temp = "";
        String str;
        for (int index = 0; index < inputPattern.size(); index++) {
            str = inputPattern.get(index);
            // First see if the second character in Array List is digit or not.
            // If digit, nothing should be done. If not, replace/insert the corresponding index from master list
            // Sometimes only one swara might be there. Ex: S,R,G,M,P,D,N 
            if (((str.length() == 1)) || (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(1)) != true)) {
         // Append with index.
                // first find the corresponsing element to be replaced from baseOctave.
                for (int index2 = 0; index2 < baseOctave.size(); index2++) {
                    if (baseOctave.get(index2).startsWith(Character.toString(str.charAt(0)))) {
                        temp = baseOctave.get(index2);
                        break;
                    }

                }
                str = str.replace(Character.toString(str.charAt(0)), temp);

            }
            inputPattern.set(index, str);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your pattern elements will always be one char with one digit? Abbreviations are always one character?

Comment: Correct. I have many instances of baseOctave and it always has combination of following: letters S,R,G,M,P,D,N followed by 1-4 digits. Example: S1 R2 S4 G1 G4 M3 P1  However my pattern may omit these suffixes for easy handling. So I will pass the base octave and then the patterns so that depending on the base octave, pattern will be modified to include these suffix.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that abbreviation is only one character and that in full pattern second character is always digit. Code below relies on this assumptions, so please inform me if they are wrong.

```
        static String replace(String string, Collection<String> patterns) {
            Map<Character, String> replacements = new HashMap<Character, String>(patterns.size());
            for (String pattern : patterns) {
                replacements.put(pattern.charAt(0), pattern);
            }

            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
                Character c = string.charAt(i);
                char next = i < string.length() - 1 ? string.charAt(i + 1) : ' ';

                String replacement = replacements.get(c);
                if (replacement != null && (next <= '0' || next >= '9')) {
                    result.append(replacement);
                } else {
                    result.append(c);
                }
            }

            return result.toString();
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ArrayList<String> baseOctave = new ArrayList<String>();
            baseOctave.add("S1");
            baseOctave.add("R2");
            baseOctave.add("G4");
            baseOctave.add("M2");
            baseOctave.add("P3");
            baseOctave.add("D1");
            baseOctave.add("N1");

            System.out.println(replace("S,,R.,M''-", baseOctave));
            System.out.println(replace("S1,G.,M,D1", baseOctave));
            System.out.println(replace("", baseOctave));
            System.out.println(replace("S", baseOctave));
        }
```

Results:

```
 S1,,R2.,M2''-
 S1,G4.,M2,D1

 S1
```

Comment: Edited the question as I found alternative solution after looking at your answer.